# XOR operation using lamba calculus and pré-operation

Tags: lambda-calculus

I recently posted a question with a similar title, but reading the community guidelines, I decided to improve it :)

We can define the $AND$, $OR$ and $NOT$ operations in terms of the $T$ and $F$ operators and the standard combiners as follows:

$K \equiv \lambda xy.x$

$S \equiv \lambda xyz.xz(yz)$

The logical operations will then be

AND (pós-fixed):
$AND \equiv F \equiv SK$

Ex: $(TT)(AND) \equiv TTF \equiv T(TF) \equiv T$

OR (in-fixed):
$OR \equiv T \equiv K$

Ex: $(T)(OR)(T) \equiv TTT \equiv T(TT) \equiv T$

NOT (pós-fixed):
$NOT \equiv FT \equiv (SK)K$

Ex: $T(NOT) \equiv TFT \equiv T(FT) \equiv F $

$p \to q \equiv \neg p \lor q \equiv (pFT)Tq \equiv p FTT q$

So the conditional is an in-fixed operation.

With all that said, let's get to the problem.

Define a lambda term $X$ that corresponds to the logical “or exclusive” operation, ie,
$Xpq = T$ if $p$ and $q$ have different logical values ​​and $Xpq = F$ otherwise.

In other words, the problem wants a prefixed description of the XOR operation in terms of the lambda calculus

$p \veebar q \equiv (p \lor q) \land \neg(p \land q) \equiv (p T q)((pqF)FT)F $

Right now I can't follow up to produce something like $Xpq$...any tips?
Since $X$ has to be described in terms of $T$ and $F$.

Comment: I'm rather confused by your definitions, since we have $(AND) FT \equiv T$ but we would expect $(AND) FT \equiv F$.

Comment: @MarkSaving I added some examples

Comment: Thanks, that makes more sense. I never realised it was possible to do things this way. That's quite intriguing.